# For a 2n-bit binary number, how many possible values are there such that half the bits are set to 1 (including leading zeros)??

Tags: combinations

So for n = 1 you'd have 01 and 10. (2 possibilities)

For n = 2 you'd have 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100. (6 possibilities)

How do I find the general formula for any positive integer value of n?

Comment: Hint: you want to _choose_ $n$ of the $2n$ bits to be 1s

Answer (score 2):

You choose $n$ out of $2n$ positions to write a $1$, so $2n\choose n$.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. but i don't get why you have to use binomial coefficients. isn't the formula for the possibilities for arranging k elements in a row just k! ? so that means that if i have a string "0011", then the amount of permutations of that string should be 4! ?

Comment: @Reneo No, that causes over-counting.  For example, label the digits 0-a,0-b,1-a,1-b.  The 4! enumeration would  **wrongly distinguish** between (for example) 0-a,0-b,1-a,1-b and 0-a,0-b,1-b,1-a.  In general, if you start with $(2n)!$ permutations, then you have to adjust re each combination of the $n$ 1's will be wrongly counted $n!$ times.  Similarly, you have to adjust for each combination of the $n$ 0's being wrongly overcounted.  This explains the fraction $$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)(n!)}.$$